# Why doesn't this python decorator print the value from the original function?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I'm trying to learn decorators in Python and every time I think I get it I come across an issue such as this. I can't figure out why the print statement from `my_func` won't display and instead I get 'None' returned. If I include `func` in my return statement in my wrapper `return (func, wrapper)` I get an error saying tuple object not callable. What is wrong with this example?

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper():
        decoration = "decorated"
        print(decoration)
    return wrapper

@my_dec
def my_func():
    a = "Original"
    print (a)

print(my_func())
```

Comment: You could improve your question by including the expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never calling the wrapped `func` in your `wrapper`. Add a call, for example:

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper():
        decoration = "decorated"
        print(decoration)
        # Call the decorated function and return what it returns
        return func()

    return wrapper

@my_dec
def my_func():
    a = "Original"
    print (a)

print(my_func())
```

would now produce (since `func()` [implicitly returns `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)):

```
decorated
Original
None
```

> If I include `func` in my return statement in my wrapper `return func, wrapper` I get an error saying tuple object not callable.

The error must've come from you doing something like:

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper():
        decoration = "decorated"
        print(decoration)

    # Now `my_dec` returns a tuple instead of a function
    return func, wrapper
```

Remember that decorating [is (roughly) equivalent to just doing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
def my_func():
    ...

my_func = my_dec(my_func)
```

Your `my_dec()` decorator now returned a tuple `(func, wrapper)` instead of a wrapper function, so when you try to call `my_func()`, you're actually trying to "call" the tuple that has been assigned to `my_func`.

As a good measure you should learn how to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which is a convenience function for invoking `update_wrapper()`, which updates the *wrapper* function to look like *func*:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_dec(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        decoration = "decorated"
        print(decoration)
        return func()

    return wrapper
```

Without it you'd get:

```
In [4]: print(my_func.__name__)
wrapper
```

and with wraps:

```
In [9]: print(my_func.__name__)
my_func
```

It copies over other useful attributes as well, such as `__doc__`.

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thank you very much. I will be exploring functools.wraps now too.